# Deleting element from array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove the first element from array which I getting from xml file. I tried to use splice method but it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

```
.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'my.xml',
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        var array = [];
        var data = $.xml2json(xml)['#document'];
        that.array = data.contacts;
    }
})
```

data:

[image]

Comment: can you share the output json and what you want to delete from it?

Comment: couldn't see where you're using splice method...

Comment: here is my array how looks like [link](http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160331/qiss48b7.png) 
I'd like to delete element with index 0

Comment: @Christian which part do you want to remove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have attached a screenshot of your Object data then you can use `Array.prototype.shift()` to remove the first entry in the array:

```
var array = [];
var data = $.xml2json(xml)['#document'];
array = data.contact.name.shift(); // <----this will remove the first entry in the array.
```

a sample demo:

```js
var array = [];
var data = {
  contact: {
    name: [{
      name: "one"
    }, {
      name: "two"
    }, {
      name: "three"
    }]
  }
};
array = data.contact.name.shift(); // <----this will remove the first entry in the array.
document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, 0, 3);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

Find the index of the element you want to remove (using `indexOf`) and then use splice to remove it....

```
var idx = that.array.indexOf(theIndexyouWantToRemove);
that.array.splice(idx, 1);
```

If its definitely the first element always, then you could use `shift()`.

Comment: Pleasure. Tick as correct if it answers your question :)